# Multisite WPLANG won't save

Tags: multisite, multi-language, localization, l10n

I have a multisite workpress install (v 3.3.2).  I'm trying to save the WPLANG field but nothing happens.  I get the confirmation message "Site options updated", but the field is still blank.  And when I query it with get_locale, it get the default 'en_US'.

I've tried entering in:

ja_JP

'ja_JP'

"ja_JP"

ja-JP

'ja-JP'

"ja-JP"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a specific language in a multi-site the language files must be available in the language directory, usually in `wp-content/languages`. So if you want to set the language to `ja_JP` a file `ja_JP.mo` must exist there.
You can get the language files from the [SVN repository](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/).

Comment: Thank you toscho!

That's the last step that I missed...saving the .mo file to wp-content/languanges.

I had only saved it to wp-content/themes/mytheme/languages.

It only makes sense logically now in retrospect that that was not the right place to put it.

I guess I won't be needing the full language files since I only want specific portions of the site to be translated.

Thank you thank you!